# Can a RadioButton replace the title in a TitledBorder in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, radio-button

Is it possible to create a TitledBorder with a [RadioButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) instead of the "title" string? It would be just like a standard [TitledBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html), but rather than having a string represent the box encompassed by the border, I'd like to use a radio button instead.

[image]

For instance, in the example above, I'd like have a radio button in place of the string, "Titled Border".

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in which the solution to this would fit? Or maybe an example (e.g. an image or website link) of what you're talking about?

Comment: What research have you done / things have you tried so far?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA I edited the question to be a clearer representation of what I believe you were asking. If the edit is approved, can you check back and confirm that this is what you were asking about?

Comment: No, borders aren't interactive. What's the [actual goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland: I want to group a set of text fields. they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Search the web for "ComponentTitledBorder" and you'll find some examples, most of which are derivation of the old Tame Swing hacks from way back when.

Comment: Update your question to show the goal and what you [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449347/can-a-radiobutton-replace-the-title-in-a-titledborder-in-swing?noredirect=1#comment43339768_27449347).

Comment: `CardLayout` would be a good alternative for this.

Comment: @trashgod Actually, I've used this in conjunction with `CardLayout`. Of course, there'd be more than one radio for it to make sense.